# Коли відбувається чергування приголосних?

Tags: чергування

Знайшов [купу інформації](https://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=8&tdmua=%D7%E5%F0%E3%F3%E2%E0%ED%ED%FF-%EF%F0%E8%E3%EE%EB%EE%F1%ED%E8%F5-%E7%E2%F3%EA%B3%E2) про **чергування приголосних**, але нічого не знайшов про те, як визначити **коли відбувається чергування**. Взагалі, є якісь **правила** стосовно цього чи просто треба запам'ятовувати?

Наприклад, як визначити чи є у словах "рибалка", "папка" чергування якщо не пам'ятаєш?

Comment: Не зовсім зрозумію суть питання. Рибал***к***а — (кому?) рибал***ц***і — (чий?) рибал***ч***ин; пап***к***а — (де?) у пап***ц***і; по-моєму, очевидно, що в цих словах чергування відбувається (а як же інакше можна сказати «кому?»/«де?»). Чи Ви маєте на увазі якісь суто формальні правила, якими міг би користуватися, наприклад, іноземець, що зовсім не знає мови, або автоматична система? (Але тоді, по-моєму, варто точніше окреслити категорію слів, для якої потрібні правила, наприклад, «іменники» або «іменники 1-ї відміни» абощо. Чи Ви справді хочете правила для всіх частин мови?)

Comment: Так. Я про правила для іноземця чи програми. Правила для хоча б якихось частин мови. Мене цікавить чи існують вони взагалі, чи просто треба орієнтуватись по пам'яті.

Comment: Хіба же [вчити](http://javot.net/mova/orf.htm#a22 "наприклад, є новіші, зьвісно") і дивити на місця, де зазвичай такі зьміни бувають — до стику наростків, кінцївки дїӧслів тошчо. Відповідь буде дуже великою.

Comment: Увів в ґуґлі "таблиця правил з української мови чергування приголосних" і перемкнув на зображення. Отримав купу таблиць з відповідями. Такі таблиці не влаштовують?